# How to disable All Face and Vertex modes when vertex painting?

Tags: vertex-paint

I know the options are available in older builds of Blender, and can be ticked in vertex paint mode, but I cannot find them in the current version. Anyone know how I can paint vertexes on specific faces only?

Answer (score 1):

This option can be found beneath the 3D View. Its icon is a cube with a grid on it. [image]